# How can I allow my application to be manipulated by Javascript hosted in a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

I've found stackoverflow questions answering how to inject javascript into a WebBrowser element, but I'd like to know how to allow javascript code in the WebBrowser control to interact with my application. For example, a web developer could do something along the lines of

```
ghostmancersBrowser.app.color="red";
```

This would cause the color scheme of the application to switch to red.

This is just an example - I don't need exactly this, I'd just like to know where to get started.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ObjectForScripting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) property of the `WebBrowser` control to provide this sort of functionality. Basically, this allows you to expose part of your application to Javascript running inside the `WebBrowser` control.

What you'd need to do is:

1. Have a class that can be instantiated which allows your application to be manipulated (to set the colour scheme to red, as per your example).
2. In the form that contains the WebBrowser control, set its `ObjectForScripting` to be an instance of said class.
3. In Javascript executed in the WebBrowser control, call methods on said object. If one of the methods was called `SetAppColourScheme` your Javascript would be `window.external.SetAppColourScheme('red')`.